# Jupyter markdown: Curly brace symbole doesn't show correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to write a mathematical equation in jupyter notebook markdown, this equation have a Curly brace '{' symbole.
I wrote this code :

```
$$M=\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
  \begin{aligned}
    2\,x&+3\,y&-4\,z&=&7\\
    -x&+8\,y&   &=&3\\
    \frac{2}{3}\,x&+\frac{13}{2}\,y&-5\,z&=&\frac{14}{5}\\
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
$$
```

when running the cell I get this:

[image]

instead of the correct one: 
[image]

So I don't know what the problem is, any idea?
PS: I have python3

Comment: It's using the wrong font. Have you tried clearing your browser cache and loading again? Are you trying to set any fonts?

Comment: Is what you see reproducible if you go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and click `launch binder` and then paste your code in a notebook after session comes up? (The result looked good when I did.)

Comment: @Wayne thank you, what you said worked correctly but how can I fix the problem in my localhost?

Comment: @Chris I opened my notebook file in a new navigator but nothing changed, the only thing I wrote is that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the probleme was that mathJax wasn't rendering correctly,and so were all mathematical expressions.so to fix it, click on **right button >> Math settings>>Math renderer>>SVG**.
[image]